# Does C parameter in Linear SVM guarantee the margin does not increase?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

From my understanding a large value of the C parameter in SVM decreases the number of misclassified instances and narrows the margin. My question is - considering that SVM with linear kernel is used, with soft margin - does increasing the value of C always guarantees that the margin is not getting bigger or there is a chance that it still can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this backwards. We are optimizing for $\min_w \frac{||w||^2}{2} + C\mathcal L(w,X,Y)$ where I've simplified notation. Clearly, if we set $C \rightarrow 0$ then we will be only optimizing for $||w||^2$ in which case $w = 0$, and the margin will tend to infinity. Likewise, as $C \rightarrow \infty$, the second term dominates, and $||w||$ can increase arbitrarily as its contribution to the objective becomes negligible, resulting in the margin decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to vote for your response, but thank you for the explanations!

Comment: You can still accept the answer I believe